# Cannot Edit A file on Source tab of Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: html, javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to edit the javascript function inside an HTML page before it gets called.

I can't edit it under source tab. I can't backspace or edit it. Nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should really have been asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead. I've answered it here anyway.

You cannot edit HTML pages in the Sources tab unless you have a Workspace set up. Check out [Set Up Persistence with DevTools Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en)
 for setting this up. Recommended if the code is yours.

However, you can set breakpoints on the JavaScript code within the `<script>` tags in the HTML page. This means that once you hit the breakpoint, you can run code into the Console to modify the state of your application, before continuing the execution as normal.

You could also run code as the breakpoint gets hit automatically by putting the code inside a [Conditional Breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en) instead. Chrome allows you to execute any arbitrary statements into the condition. See example below:

[image: Conditional Breakpoint]

Comment: Apologies. I thought I was in stack overflow when I asked this. This makes sense after all my research too, will look more into breakpoints. Thank you